# How to scroll in a for loop from an element to another?

Tags: python, for-loop

I wanna scroll sys.argv from the second to the penultimate argument. why it doesn't work?

```
for arg in sys.argv[1: :len(sys.argv)-1] :
    print arg
```

Comment: You put a `:` too much: `sys.argv[1:len(sys.argv)-1]`. Also, you can use negative indexes: `sys.argv[1:-1]`.

Answer (score 6):

You have a mistake in your code: you shouldn't put two colons, but just one. Here's how it works:

- In order to exclude *n* **first** elements, the syntax is `[n:]`.
- In order to exclude *n* **last** elements, you don't need to count the number of elements in an array. Instead, you use: `[:-n]` syntax.
- If you want to exclude first *x* elements **and** last *y* elements, you can combine both: `[x:y]`.

In your case, to get the array without the first and the last arguments, you may simply do:

```
sys.argv[1:-1]
```

Like this:

```
for arg in sys.argv[1:-1]:
    print arg
```

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus: I thought it's clear enough, since I provided the correct syntax **and** explained how the syntax works. Since it appears that it's not, I edited my answer to include the actual mistake in OP's code.

Comment: Thanks for that ... since OP wants to know "why it doesn't work?", I think it's important to tell them ... anyway, downvote replaced with upvote :-)

Comment: I thought this explanation was an excellent example of slowly building up the syntax in steps and then (and only then) giving the actual code fix.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you have too many colons, resulting in an [extended slice](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-16).

Because of the extra colon in `[1::len(sys.argv)-1]` (the space between the colons in your version is unnecessary, and may be what confused you), you're saying:

- Give me all the elements from index `1` ...
- ...to the end (because there's nothing between the first and second colons) ...
- with a *stride* of `len(sys.argv)-1`.

Obviously, if you start at the 2nd element of a sequence and then stride forward by `len(sequence) - 1`, you get to the end, and there's nothing left.

If you drop the extra colon, your code will work ...

```
for arg in sys.argv[1:len(sys.argv)-1]:
    print arg
```

... but Python allows you to use [negative indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/493057/1014938) to count from the end of the sequence you're slicing, so you can replace the whole thing with:

```
for arg in sys.argv[1:-1]:
    print arg
```

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv` is a `list`, so you can apply [slicing](http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/) in order to get only a certain part of the list, for example if you only want to iterate from element two to the penultimate.
Generally, if `lst` is a list

```
lst[0]
```

is the first element of the list, and

```
lst[-1]
```

is the last.
Example:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> x[1:-1]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

With slicing, your `for` loop should look like

```
for arg in sys.argv[1:-1]:
    print(arg)
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the actual bug, which is the extra colon in the slice.