# Unable to understand negative string slicing in python

Tags: python, string

Example code:

```
name = "i am a student"
print(name[::-1])
```

Output:

```
tneduts a ma i
```

Comment: have a look here to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493046/i-dont-understand-slicing-with-negative-bounds-in-python-how-is-this-supposed

Answer (score 1):

The last part of a slice denotes steps:

`sequence[start:stop:steps]`

As the last part is steps, it goes on the string on steps of -1:

```
i am a student
             ^
i am a student
            ^
i am a student
           ^
```

Answer (score 0):

String_index[start:stop:step]
You set the start to 0 and the end to the last element and the step -1 which mean its gonna go from first to last but reversed