# Python substring has what defaults for x,y when z is negative? (this has nothing to do with x,y being negative)

Tags: python, string, substring, default, negative-number

For a Python substring, I'm confused on defaults of x,y when z is negative

Next lines: the defaults for x:y are no problem understanding because z is positive

```
alpha = "abcdef"
print(alpha[0:6:1])  #abcdef
print(alpha[::1])      #abcdef    defaults for x,y change this to [0:6:1]
```

But when change to a negative z I'm confused. I would think [::z] becomes [0:6:z] regardless of z being +1 or -1. But seems defaults for x,y are different when the z is pos or neg

```
print(alpha[0:6:-1])   # (no defaults example) prints nothing - OK
print(alpha[::1])      # abcdef    default [::1] becomes [0:6:1] - OK
print(alpha[::-1])     # fedcba    default [::-1] not becomes [0:6:-1] - why different x,y defaults?
```

### Response to suggested duplicate

I don't think this is a duplicate - the other question is about negative x,y. This questions is about x,y *defaults* when z is negative. This question involves a double colon syntax - that does not appear in the "duplicate question" reference.

Comment: Ya, that was a bad dupe closure (wasn't me!). I've nominated it for reopening, although I believe I recall another dupe that does answer this.

Comment: I believe the "why" though is simply convenience. If the defaults didn't swap, it would be necessary to specify them every time a negative step is used, which means `coll[::-1]` would never be correct, and would need to be `coll[len(coll):-1:-1]`, which is ugly af. It makes sense if you think of the step as the direction you travel in. There are no elements when you travel backwards from index 0.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I believe this is an appropriate target https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63766793

Comment: @cigien Their questions appears to not be what a negative step is, but why a negative step reverses the default values of the other two "arguments" of the slice. None of those answers seem to address that.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Hmm, that seems to be covered under "I don't understand how this works", but you might be right. Note however that deciding whether a question is a duplicate doesn't really have anything to do with the *answers* on the proposed target. If the answers don't cover some aspect of the question, then an additional answer should be added on the target.

Comment: Thanks, carcigenicate, for re-open

Comment: Here is my conclusion.

Comment: Tests for rules: (sorry, I don't see how to designate code in a comment)

alpha = "abcdef"

print("2 "+alpha[6:0:-1])   # fedcba   no defaults, -z: defaults are normal

print("3 "+alpha[0:6:-1])   # nothing  no defaults, -z: defaults are normal

print("4 "+alpha[6::-1])    # fedcba    x explicit, y default=len+1, -z. w/ one default, defaults are normal

print("5 "+alpha[:6:-1])    # nothing   default x=0, explicit y, -z. rule: w/ one default, defaults are normal

print("6 "+alpha[::-1])     # fedcba   *if default x&y AND -z*: Defaults changed to x=len, y= "0-1"(so 0 included)

Comment: Rules:

1 - Order of evaluation will always be x to y. 

2 - Defaults are x=0, y=len+1, z = +1

2B - *Default exception* if x,y both defaults AND -z then defaults change to: x = len+1, y="0-1" (so include 0)