# How to find the top 3 lists in a list of list based on the last element in python?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a list of list in Python:

```
list_all = [['orange', 'the dress', '127456'],
            ['pink', 'cars', '543234'],
            ['dark pink' 'doll', '124098'],
            ['blue', 'car', '3425'],
            ['sky blue', 'dress', '876765']]
```

I want to return top 3 lists which have the highest count of numbers in the last part. Like this:

```
result = [['sky blue', 'dress', '876765'],
         ['pink', 'cars', '543234'],
         ['orange', 'the dress', '127456']]
```

I just cannot find the logic to do this. I have tried a lot, but just got stuck with one line of code:

```
for each in list_all:
    if len(each[-1].split(','))
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `sorted()`:

```
sorted(list_all, key = lambda x: int(x[-1]))[-3:][::-1]
```

Output:

```
[['sky blue', 'dress', '876765'],
 ['pink', 'cars', '543234'],
 ['orange', 'the dress', '127456']]
```

Comment: Good answer! As the OP is new to python, maybe you want to explain why the code works. I can imagine especially the negative indexing is new to them.

Comment: I think others have already done that better than I would: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493046/i-dont-understand-slicing-with-negative-bounds-in-python-how-is-this-supposed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing

Comment: It's still best to include some explanation here, and link to that for further reading (because you don't want your answer to become unhelpful if that answer is modified or deleted)

Comment: Also instead of the slicing and reversing shenanigans, you can just do `sorted(..., reverse=True)[:3]`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi feel free to edit it

Answer (score 2):

Use a lambda

Modification from: [How to sort a 2D list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18563680/how-to-sort-a-2d-list)

```
result  = sorted(list_all ,key=lambda l:int(l[-1]), reverse=True)[:3]
```

This returns

```
[['sky blue', 'dress', '876765'],
 ['pink', 'cars', '543234'],
 ['orange', 'the dress', '127456']]
```

Comment: 1 you're sorting by the wrong element, 2 this doesn't return what you say it does as you've just directly copied the answer from the other question you linked to

Comment: still incorrect

Comment: I believe it works, changed the key

Comment: well it works now, not before you changed it to ```int(...)```

Comment: Alright cool just checking!